# Not able to typecast from String to a class in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Getting following exception while hitting a Rest endpoint. How do I typecast from `String` to `ProtectPanReplyType` class?

Error:

```
Error - Request: http://localhost:9090/hosted-payments-webapp-1.0.0/pan/protect 
raised java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gsicommerce.api.checkout.ProtectPanReplyType cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**ProtectPanServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class ProtectPanServiceImpl implements ProtectPanService {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendProtectPanRequest(ProtectPan protectPan) {
        String pan = protectPan.getPaymentAccountNumber();
        String tenderClass = protectPan.getTenderClass();

        String protectPanRequest = XMLHelper.createProtectPanRequest(pan, tenderClass);
        System.out.println("protectPanRequest = " + protectPanRequest);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        try {
            response = ApiClientUtils.callClientByEndpointandMessage(protectPanRequest, DEV_PUBLIC_API_URL,
                    ProtectPanReplyType.class);
            System.out.println("response.getClass() = " + response.getClass());

            //DOES NOT WORK
            //ProtectPanReplyType protectPanReplyType = (ProtectPanReplyType)response.getBody();

            //THROWS ClassCastException HERE
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
        } catch (JiBXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

**ApiClientUtils.java**

```
public ResponseEntity<String> callClientByEndpointandMessage(String xmlRequest, String endpoint, Class<?> replyType) throws JiBXException {
    HttpEntity<String> request = createRequestForUser("username", "secret",xmlRequest);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restOperations.postForEntity(endpoint, request, String.class);
    ResponseEntity formattedResponse = new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    try {
        Object jibxObject = JibxHelper.unmarshalMessage(response.getBody(), replyType);
        formattedResponse = new ResponseEntity(jibxObject, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (JiBXException e) {
        FaultResponseType faultResponse = JibxHelper.unmarshalMessage(response.getBody(), FaultResponseType.class);
        formattedResponse = new ResponseEntity(faultResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return formattedResponse;
}
```

**ProtectPan.java**

```
public class ProtectPan {

    @JsonProperty("paymentAccountNumber")
    private String paymentAccountNumber;

    @JsonProperty("tenderClass")
    private String tenderClass;

    public String getPaymentAccountNumber() {
        return paymentAccountNumber;
    }

    public String getTenderClass() {
        return tenderClass;
    }
}
```

**ProtectPanReplyType.java**

```
public class ProtectPanReplyType {

    private String token;
    private List<Element> anyList = new ArrayList<Element>();
    private String sessionId;

    //getters and setter removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: You cannot cast from String to ProtectPanReplyType. You have to parse the data inside the String and create a new ProtectPanReplyType  with this data.

Comment: So, when I do `response.getBody()` which has a return type of `String` does not get printed on the console and throws an exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ResponseEntity<ProtectPanReplyType>` instead `ResponseEntity<String>`
2. Build and **Return** ProtectPanReplyType from your `restOperations.postForEntity()`

Comment: That method is getting used by number of other endpoints and the return type would differ based on the input. So, it could be `ProtectPanReplyType` class for one instance and `CmpiLookupReply` for another instance.

Comment: ProtectPanReplyType  and CmpiLookupReply are having anything in common? ie. are they extending/implementing same superclass/interface? If yes, you can return the super type.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But this is what I am trying: `return restOperations.postForEntity(endpoint, request, replyType);`. Not sure how  would I handle the `FaultResponse` object though.

Answer (score 0):

Was finally able to get the object after making following changes.

**ApiClientUtils.java**

```
public ResponseEntity<?> callClientByEndpointandMessage(String xmlRequest, String endpoint, Class<?> replyType) throws JiBXException {
        HttpEntity<String> request = createRequestForUser("payment", "SONitc2m8y", xmlRequest);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restOperations.postForEntity(endpoint, request, String.class);
        ResponseEntity<?> formattedResponse = null;
        try {
            Object jibxObject = JibxHelper.unmarshalMessage(response.getBody(), replyType);
            formattedResponse = new ResponseEntity(jibxObject, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (JiBXException e) {
            FaultResponseType faultResponse = JibxHelper.unmarshalMessage(response.getBody(), FaultResponseType.class);
            formattedResponse = new ResponseEntity(faultResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return formattedResponse;
    }
```

**ProtectPanServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> sendProtectPanRequest(ProtectPan protectPan) {
    String pan = protectPan.getPaymentAccountNumber();
    String tenderClass = protectPan.getTenderClass();

    String protectPanRequest = XMLHelper.createProtectPanRequest(pan, tenderClass);
    ResponseEntity<?> response = null;
    try {
        response = publicApiClientUtils.callClientByEndpointandMessage(protectPanRequest, DEV_PUBLIC_API_URL, ProtectPanReplyType.class);
        ProtectPanReplyType protectPanReplyType = (ProtectPanReplyType) response.getBody();
        System.out.println("protectPanReplyType = " + protectPanReplyType);
    } catch (JiBXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```